# Where can I download PowerBuilder 8?

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am looking for a Sybase [PowerBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBuilder) 8.0 setup. I found http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1013232, but the all dowload links are broken.

Where can I download PowerBuilder 8?

Comment: I threw 12 unopened box sets of Powerbuilder 8 in the bin on Tuesday... if only i'd known :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might ask Sybase, but I doubt they'd sell it to you. AFAIK, they haven't sold PB8 in about 8 years, and it [hasn't been supported in 6 years](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1027975). The current eval (11.5 at the time of this writing) is available off their [main product page](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerbuilder), if *free* is what you're after.

If it's *PB8* you need, then you may be out of luck. Occasionally, you see an old copy sold on eBay, but I've had someone suggest to me that the license terms don't allow resale, so I'm not sure how legal this option is. (I'm no lawyer; maybe you'd want to ask that on "Litigation Overflow".) I'm sure I can leave the even less legal options up to your imagination.

Availability might be another reason to argue for an upgrade, beyond [the technical reasons and new features](http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/changes_to_powerbuilder.html), like operating system support. The [PHBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) won't like it, but then again, some live to aggravate PHBs; not you I'm sure.

Sorry, and good luck,

Terry

Comment: PB8 *is* supported today. I work in a bank in Argentina that uses it and wich has support from Sybase.

Answer (score 2):

PB8? Sounds like you have to work on an existing system. The company that owns the code and is sponsoring the project *surely* has a legal license for you to use. It would need to provide you access to its copy if you don't have your own to work with.

Barring that, if you have access to the original code, it should be possible to migrate the application to a newer version of PB, although as Terry notes, PB8 is out of support and I'm not sure if there would be difficulties migrating. There would most certainly be some if the code features any special customizations or usage of now obsolete objects. In that case I can see how you would probably be best served by having PB8 to make adjustments noted by the migration assistant before completing the code conversion.